# Replace Dim with Private in VB files with Resharper 7 Custom Pattern

Tags: resharper

I am a fairly new resharper user. I wanted to create a custom pattern that will show a suggestion under Dim and replace it with Private. I filled out the custom pattern like so:

```
 Find: Dim              Replace : Private
```

But it doesn't work, I presume I am not doing it correctly. What do I need to fill out to get this custom pattern up and running?

Comment: Seems like a bug. But won't a simple search and replace work for you? And even there I see some problems because the in method declarations won't like the above.

Comment: Just in case I created an issue in youtrack. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-330140

Comment: That is what I am doing at the moment but people keep doing it, I was hoping making it a resharper warning would solve the issue. Thanks for making the youtrack issue. Hmmm, I didn't consider Methods though.. I may need to rethink this. Do you want make an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Certainly in 6.0, R# pattern-based search and replace in my experience seems to work much better in situations involving complete code pieces, rather than just single words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Resharper 7.0 or below this is apparently not possible. I got this reply from the Resharper team.

> Sorry, at the moment ReSharper doesn't support class-level search with
>   pattern in VB.NET.

But they might add it in R# 8.0

You can vote on [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-330139) to make it happen faster ;-)